# Check against multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got two tables in a database with the following columns:

**Table1**

```
athleteId | sportTypeId
 205      |    5
 206      |    5
 206      |    6
 207      |    4
 208      |    1
 208      |    4
```

Due to an error I made (whoops), the second table has some information like this:

*Table2**

```
athleteId | sportTypeId
  205     |    4
  206     |    4
  207     |    4
  208     |    4
  NULL    |    4
```

I assigned the wrong `athleteId` to some athletes, so what I need to do is check every row in `Table2` and see if it has a matching row in `Table1`. The rows containing `athleteId 205` and `206` from `Table2` would have the `athleteId` set to `NULL` (they don't have a `sportTypeId` of `4` in `Table1`).  `athleteId 207` and `208` would remain (they do have a row in `Table1` with `sportTypeId of 4`).

Notice that some athletes appear twice in `Table1`.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, you're asking for a way to delete rows from `Table2` where there is no matching row in `Table1`, correct? If so, here's how to do it:

```
DELETE t2.*
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t2.athleteId = t1.athleteId AND t2.sportTypeId = t1.sportTypeId
WHERE t1.athleteId IS NULL;
```

The reason this works is because of the left join and the where clause. The left join will cause `t1.athleteId` to be null whenever a matching record isn't found in `Table1`.

**Edit:** If you just want to set the `athleteId` to null instead of deleting the whole row, it's a small modification:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.athleteId = null
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t2.athleteId = t1.athleteId AND t2.sportTypeId = t1.sportTypeId
WHERE t1.athleteId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Tried to clarify exactly what I meant by "remove". I think you go the gist of it though.  Thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something in my database.  I'm not getting the expected results.  Would `NULL` entries in `athleteId` in `Table2` make a difference? I've updated my question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt That shouldn't make a difference in this case. Can you give an example of unexpected results?

Comment: Doh! My mistake.  I had to add in a couple filters to filter out other parts of my table, but this solution works! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

```
update table2 set athleteid = null where not exists (
    select *
    from table1
    where athleteid = table2.athleteid and sporttypeid = table2.sporttypeid
)
```